# I saw x while y

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, subject-verb-agreement

I stumbled across a sentence recently

> I **saw** a baby bus **while** its proud mother showed it the way

I feel like **while** should be replaced with **as**, or **saw** with **watched**. Can anyone tell me if this sentence is correct as is and why or why not?

Comment: "A baby *bus*"? Are you sure that was the sentence? Also can you try to explain what you want the sentence to mean?

Comment: Lol, yes I'm sure that was the sentence. As for what I want it to mean, it's not my sentence!

Comment: OK but where did you see this?

Comment: It was a meme that my friend showed me.

Comment: Can you post or link to the meme?

Comment: Once I get home I can post a link, but can you explain why that's relevant?

Comment: The same words can have different meanings depending on the context. See [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/41273) for more details.

Comment: I see. So basically whether or not this sentence is correct (specifically the use of saw and while) is entirely dependent on context?